# Creating Sparkline Chart inside table in data studio

Tags: looker-studio

I am trying to create the spark line chart in the row level for a given table but i am not getting any options to add the chart in the table using Google data studio.

Refer the attached screenshot for details.

[image: Sample example]

Comment: Any leads from community visualizations?

Answer (score 0):

The only things you can add within a table are bars (single) or heatmaps.

It may be possible in future when the community visualisations are made generally available. Keep your eye one that here:

[community visualisations](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/visualization/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is [a post on how to create sparklines yourself](https://michaelhoweely.com/2019/04/14/an-overview-of-all-google-data-studio-chart-types-in-2019/). Google Datastudio does now support sparklines out-of-the-box but I am not sure if you can add them in table rows (it seems there is no documentation on it though).

[image]